# BD-ROM Drive suddenly appeared in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, blu-ray

Today I noticed that a "BD-ROM Drive" appears in My Computer.

[image]

I do not remember installing anything that would've done that.

What could've caused this?

Comment: Do you have some drive emulator software such as alchool or daemon tools installed on your system?

Comment: Most likely a virtual drive with Daemon Tools or something..!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The likely explanation would be that you installed virtual drive emulation software such as Daemon Tools, Alcohol 52%/120%, or PowerISO (or another disc-burning software that has drive-emulation capability).

In most cases depending on the version and program used, a virtual drive is added automatically after install.

Answer (score 2):

BD-ROM DRIVE means Blu-Ray Disk Read Only Memory Drive.

It usually appears when you install a Virtual Drive using softwares like Daemon Tools, PowerISO, etc, and it is used to mount .ISO files and many other data formats.

Answer (score 2):

In Daemon Tools you can also click on "Remove all drives" and this will get rid of all the unwanted BD-ROM drives

Answer (score 1):

I used DAEMON Tools, as mentioned in other posts, and a lot of BD-ROM drives appeared on my computer; actually, they took over all the drive letters, from E: to Z:.  On my laptop, I couldn't use any USB drives.  With no drive letters remaining, when I insert a flash USB, it can't mount on Win8.

I went to disk manager under device manager and disabled several of them. After that, USB was able to mount.

The OP has only one BD-ROM, so that was not the problem in this case.  But this may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: I also used DAEMON Tools and a lot of BD-ROM drives appeared on my computer, actually they took over all the drive letters, from E: to Z:, the topic starter has only one, so that was not a problem, but on my laptop I couldn't use any USB drives. Hope this will be helpful to someone as well.